# How do I add a permanent label for selected markers using the scatter plot chart in Spotfire?

Tags: label, scatter-plot, spotfire

I have created a scatter plot between two variables in Spotfire and would like to only show labels for the markers that I select. I believe you can do this via the properties however the other markers fade in colour and the labelling is only temporary when you click back on the chart. I would like the labels to remain and all colours remain at normal transparency.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do is:

```
Right Click > Properties > Appearance > Check "Use seperate color for marked items"
```

Comment: Thanks. Helped a bit but ideally I'd like to retain the colours of all markers, including the selected ones, just without the colour fade.

Comment: I don't think that's possible @Howeitzer. The whole point of "marking" or selecting something is spotfire would be to show that it is actually selected / marked. If you didn't have labels turned on, and enabled a feature that would allow you to select an item but not change it's color or highlight it would be impossible to know what was selected... if anything.

Comment: Hmm ok. It seems odd that there is no option to label individual markers without having to make a selection.

Comment: Yeah, you could put that in as a feature request to Tibco but i think it'd be hard to dynamically assign markers without a selection.

Comment: Thanks for the help @scsimon!

Comment: No problem @Howeitzer